# convergence of series of subsequence, when original sequence converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

There is a sequence {a1, a2, a3, ...}.

Suppose that a series of this sequence converges to a constant C.

My question is,

For any subsequence {b1, b2, b3, ... } of {a1, a2, a3, ... }, 
Does the series of {bn} converges?

Comment: If you search through maths stack exchange, I'm sure you'll find an answer explaining this already! This is a standard result, and the answer is yes. If $(a_n)$ converges, every subsequence of it will converge to the same limit.

Comment: Yes, Every subsequence of it will converge to the same limit. But My question is about Convergence of series of the subsequence. The answer is "no"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the serie $\sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n/n$, it converges since it is an alternating serie, but $\sum (-1)^{2n}/(2n)=\sum_{n\geq 0}{1\over{2n}}$ does not converge.

Answer (score 0):

Yes if the convergence is absolute: if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|a_n|<\infty$ then also $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}|b_n|<\infty$.

No if the convergence is not absolute: see the counterexample given in the answer of Tsemo Aristide.